# Undefined express session in another route

Tags: node.js, express

I have login route in which I set a session for user username. When I post it through postman I get json result `"thomas"` and when I try to console.log it in route: `user-data` it says undefined. Can someone help me with this?

```
app.use(session({ secret: "thepolyglotdeveloper", cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 60000 }, saveUninitialized: true, resave: true }));

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {        
        req.session.username = 'thomas';
        res.json(req.session.username)
});

app.get('/user-data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.username) // Undefined
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably failing because postman doesn't save cookies between requests, so the cookie being "set" by postman isn't provided when you make the request to `/user-data`.

If you look at the response of the login `POST` in postman and provide it as a cookie in the `GET` request in postman, it should succeed.